# Does Deuteronomy distinguish laws written in books from those written in stone?

Tags: law, deuteronomy, moses, ten-commandments

In Exodus and later in Deuteronomy, Moses brings down tables of stone from the mountain with what is now commonly known as the Ten Commandments, including the one that commands:

> "You shall not kill." Exodus 13:9; Deut 5:17

After presenting these in Deuteronomy, Moses then says:

> "These words the Lord spoke to all your assembly at the mountain out
>   of the midst of the fire, the cloud, and the thick darkness, with a
>   loud voice; **and he added no more.** And he wrote them upon two tables of
>   stone, and gave them to me." Deut 5:22

What follows later in Deuteronomy are many more laws and punishments, which were "written in this book", and all manner of curses threatened against anyone who disobeys "all the words":

> "If you are not careful to do all the words of this law which are
>   written in this book, that you may fear this glorious and awful name,
>   the Lord your God, then the Lord will bring on you and your offspring
>   extraordinary afflictions, afflictions severe and lasting, and
>   sicknesses grievous and lasting." Deut 29:58-59

However, there are at least ten of these later laws in the book that command the Hebrew people to "kill" or "put to death" for certain transgressions (Deut 13:5, 9-10; 17:5-7; 21:21-22; 22:21-24), not to mention many more in both Exodus and Leviticus.

It doesn't seem possible to reconcile the laws written in the books with those apparently written in stone.

Is Moses implying special permission to break this particular law of God in order to punish transgressors, or are we meant to regard these two sets of laws differently?

Comment: Putting to death (allowed/encouraged in specific cases) is not the same as murdering (prohibited)...

Comment: That itself is an excellent question, even for Hebrew speakers.  See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61641/16354.  Feel free to ask me any questions about it, as it is not so "English-only" friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My translation skills are poor, but I noticed that the specific Hebrew verb used in the Ten Commandments for "kill" is not used anywhere else in the bible, let alone as 'put to death', 'kill' or 'murder'. Can you demonstrate that the distinction you make here is intended in this case, and not simply interpreted as such later?

Comment: Unfortunately, you have erred here.  The Hebrew verb is רצח, which is [Strong's H7523](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?t=kjv&strongs=h7523), and appears a number of times in the Bible, almost always in cases of murder.  It is the same verb that is discussed in the Mi Yodeya post I linked to

Comment: Again, thanks for the assistance. I see my error now, but I return to my first problem: the distinction detailed in later laws seems (to me) to be excusing a lack of self control, patience, etc (eg. in the case of Goel Hadam), rather than clarifying the original commandment. The Mi Yodeya post is an interesting discussion, but doesn't resolve the issue for me. The clincher for me here is the phrase "and he added no more", which I can't seem to ignore or dismiss. The kill-murder distinction is just one example that stands out.

Comment: He certainly distinguishes between what is written on our hearts from what is written in stone - unless you have a heart of stone!

Comment: IMHO you have a good question which I would restate as "What is the relationship between the Decalogue and the rest of the Torah?" but your example about God killing an offender is weak and kind of ruins the question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @ruminator - what is written on my heart is part of the reason I have so much trouble with these books of laws! I will take another look at it.

Comment: I didn't mean you personally. I was alluding to the new covenant, etc.

Comment: I understood what you meant. That's what makes me think we're missing something in these books of laws that seem to say 'except it's okay in this situation' so often. That doesn't sit well with me, so I'm struggling to make sense of it rather than be tempted to dismiss them.

Comment: @Ruminator, if I was to take your advice and reword the question as suggested - would it be a matter of editing this question (quite drastically), or posting another to be fair to my friend who has answered already? This is my first question asked...

Comment: You won't be able to delete it unless your friend is willing to delete the answer. So you may need to ask it anew. It is a very significant question and I think you'll get an enthusiastic response with a variety of viewpoint if the question is very simple and straightforward and not tied to such a narrow case.

Answer (score 1):

These are two parts of the same set of laws, God commanded the first "10" to the people in a more direct form, and the later commandments he told Moses to pass on to the nation.  Obviously, if the nation was told not to kill, and God gave them other commandments which involve killing, God is intending that in those cases, they should kill.  (In fact, the punishment for transgressing some of the "ten commandments" is death, as noted elsewhere in scripture.)

You appear to have been misled (understandably so) by some translations about the meaning of the words "וְלֹ֣א יָסָ֑ף", "and he added no more".  As is clear from virtually all commentaries, these words do not mean that there were no other commandments ever given following this, because of course (as you noted) there are many.

Rather, it means that there was some final point of something taking place, such as God's direct speech to the nation, or the experience of prophecy for all.  See the commentaries at the bottom of [this page](http://biblehub.com/deuteronomy/5-22.htm).  See as well [Numbers 11:25](http://biblehub.com/numbers/11-25.htm), which has the same phrase during a prophetic experience (although KJV has "and did not cease" as the translation there, many others disagree and translate it similarly to here).

To take Ellicott, for example:

> he added no more—(Ex 20:1). The pre-eminence of these ten commandments was shown in God's announcing them directly: other laws and institutions were communicated to the people through the instrumentality of Moses.

---

Just to note the meaning of of the word "יָסָ֑ף": It may be from [Strong's H5490](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/5490.htm), which is how KJV translates in Numbers,  or from [Strong's H3254](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/3254.htm), which is what it is otherwise translated as.  It is ironic that these are almost exact opposites in meaning here...

Comment: Not obviously at all. If the nation was told not to kill - full stop - then it was told not to kill - full stop. If the nation is then told to kill in certain circumstances, then the original instruction has been REPLACED, not clarified. Same with the phrase "and he added no more". If more are then added, then it renders the phrase contradictory, and you can't simply dismiss this as impossible. I'm in the process of restructuring the question, because I need to ask WHY the two parts were delivered differently.